# Trouble installing L2TP vpn protocol on Elementary

Tags: networking, vpn

I've been trying to install l2tp on my Elementary OS Hera machine. I haven't found any guide for this that is specific to Elementary, and while the related packages appear in my apt search, the option to use l2tp is not appearing in my network manager.

This is the command I entered after adding the ppa:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager-l2tp : Depends: xl2tpd but it is not installable
                        Depends: strongswan but it is not installable or
                                 libreswan but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm not sure if these dependency issues can be resolved - is l2tp simply not compatible with Elementary? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `xl2tpd` package. Here are the commands I use on Elementary OS Hera:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xl2tpd network-manager-l2tp network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

After that you can add new VPN from Network settings. And now you can see new L2TP on dropdown menu.

[image: Elementary OS Network Settings - Add L2TP VPN]

Comment: thank you for share, finally l2tp is working right now... Regards, Fabio Lima